# After wp_insert_post(), date_i18n() and date() outputs are adjusted to GMT

Tags: date, wp-insert-post

I am having a very peculiar issue on a customer's server (vps).  The code below works just fine on my servers.  Basically, a specific unix timestamp is formatted correctly and as soon as wp_insert_post() is called, the dates adjust to GMT.  For example:

```
echo "date_i18n of 1366495200: " . date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i', 1366495200 ). '<br />';
echo "date of 1366495200: " . date('Y-m-d H:i', 1366495200 ). '<br />';
// Both output >>> 2013-04-21 00:00 , correct based on server settings

 $_post = array(
            'post_type' => 'my_cpt',
            'post_title' => 'my title',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

$new_post_ID = wp_insert_post( $_post );

echo "date_i18n of 1366495200: " . date_i18n('Y-m-d H:i', 1366495200 ). '<br />';
echo "date of 1366495200: " . date('Y-m-d H:i', 1366495200 ). '<br />';
// new output >>> 2013-04-20 22:00 <<<
```

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not pass a date to `wp_insert_post()`, `get_gmt_from_date()` is called. And look at that function’s content:

```
function get_gmt_from_date($string, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    preg_match('#([0-9]{1,4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})#', $string, $matches);
    if ( ! $matches )
        return date( $format, 0 );

    $tz = get_option('timezone_string');
    if ( $tz ) {
        date_default_timezone_set( $tz );
        $datetime = date_create( $string );
        if ( ! $datetime )
            return date( $format, 0 );

        $datetime->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
        $offset = $datetime->getOffset();
        $datetime->modify( '+' . $offset / HOUR_IN_SECONDS . ' hours');
        $string_gmt = gmdate($format, $datetime->format('U'));

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    } else {
        $string_time = gmmktime($matches[4], $matches[5], $matches[6], $matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1]);
        $string_gmt = gmdate($format, $string_time - get_option('gmt_offset') * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
    }
    return $string_gmt;
}
```

It changes the time zone according to the setting in the option `timezone_string`. So go to `wp-admin/options-general.php` and set the proper time zone. Or pass a valid date per parameter `post_date`.

Comment: WordPress standardizes the PHP date to UTC, and handles timezone conversion itself. The real question is why is the timezone not UTC before calling the function.

Comment: Passing a date to post_date AND post_date_gmt worked in this case.  Some more details if it will help: WP timezone is New York and PHP date.timezone is set to US/Central. Much obliged!